# Kubernetes Docker process inside pod

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I have a Docker image with the CMD to run a Java application.

This application is being deployed to container into Kubernetes. Since, I am deploying it as a Docker image, I was expecting it as running as a Docker process. So, I just logged into the pods and was trying "**docker ps**".

But, I was surprised that it is running as a Java process and not as a docker process. I am able to see the process by "**ps -ef**"

I am confused, how does it work internally?

Comment: _How it works internally?_ I am 100% super positive that question has been beaten to death. Or, put another way: what articles have you **already read** that did not adequately address your questions? [Also, as a pedantic note: you tagged this as `kubernetes` but you asked about `docker`]

Comment: This is about docker inside kubernetes. Thats is why tagged as Kubernetes.

Comment: Technically it is below either Kubernetes or Docker and is about running applications in containers. Docker and Kubernetes are just ways of launching applications from images in a container.

Comment: I'm sure this topic has been beaten to death in some circles, but I found this article helpful in understanding what Linux containers actually are: https://jvns.ca/blog/2016/10/10/what-even-is-a-container/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As others stated, **Kubernetes uses docker internally to deploy the containers**. To explain in detail consider the cluster which has 4 nodes, 1 master and 3 slaves.

```
$ kubectl get nodes
NAME                           STATUS    ROLES     AGE       VERSION
******.mylabserver.com   Ready     master    13d       v1.10.5
******.mylabserver.com   Ready     <none>    13d       v1.10.5
******.mylabserver.com   Ready     <none>    13d       v1.10.5
******.mylabserver.com   Ready     <none>    13d       v1.10.5
```

I am deploying a pod with **nignx docker image**.

```
$ cat pod-nginx.yml 
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: alpine
  namespace: default
spec:
  containers:
  - name: alpine
    image: alpine
    command:
      - sleep
      - "3600"
    imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
  restartPolicy: Always
```

You can get the status of the pod as below:

```
$ kubectl get pods -o wide
NAME      READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE       IP           NODE
alpine    1/1       Running   0          21s       10.244.3.4   ******.mylabserver.com
```

**Kube-scheduler** will schedule the pod on one of the available nodes.

Now the pod is deployed to a server, where you can login to that particular server and find the information that you are looking for.

```
root@******:/home/user# docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                                                                            COMMAND                  CREATED              STATUS         
     PORTS               NAMES
6486de4410ad        alpine@sha256:e1871801d30885a610511c867de0d6baca7ed4e6a2573d506bbec7fd3b03873f   "sleep 3600"             58 seconds ago       Up 57 seconds  
                         k8s_alpine_alpine_default_2e2b3016-79c8-11e8-aaab-
```

Run the `docker exec` command in that server to see the process running inside.

```
root@******:/home/user# docker exec -it 6486de4410ad /bin/sh
/ # ps -eaf
PID   USER     TIME   COMMAND
    1 root       0:00 sleep 3600
    7 root       0:00 /bin/sh
   11 root       0:00 ps -eaf
/ #
```

https://kubernetes.io/docs/home/- this can give you more info about pods and how deployments happen with pods/containers.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Note that as of K8S version 1.20, the default configuration runs pods directly over containerd (i.e. not over Docker). https://kubernetes.io/blog/2020/12/02/dont-panic-kubernetes-and-docker/

Answer (score 1):

Kubernetes using the yaml file that the user provides, deploys a pod (smaller unit of Kubernetes deployment) with one or more containers in it.

You can access the containers inside the pod using the **kubectl** tool.
For example, in case your pod has one container you can open a shell inside it:

```
kubectl exec -ti <pod-name> -n <pod-namespace> bash
```

Through this shell, you can run `ps` commands and your output will be the isolated processes running inside your container.

In case you want to observe the Docker containers which Kubernetes has deployed in a node, you can connect to that node and run `docker ps` commands.